# Как найти суммы последовательных узлов в бинарном дереве?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

**Дано:** бинарное дерево (алгоритм дерева написан вручную). Число S. 
Нужно **найти последовательность узлов** (только с вверху вниз или наоборот) **в бинарном дереве, сумма которых равна S**.

Например: есть бинарное дерево, а число S = 9.
[image: example]

Решение: 3+6, 4+5, 9.

п.с. желательно, что бы это был отдельный класс, который имел доступ к классу binTree

```
#pragma once
class binTree
{
protected:
  struct Node
  {
    int Value;
    Node * pLeft;
    Node * pRight;
    Node * pParent;
    Node(int x) :Value(x), pLeft(NULL), pRight(NULL), pParent(NULL) {}
  };
  Node * m_pRoot;
  void InoderTreeWalk(Node * x);
  Node * TreeSuccessor(Node *x);
  Node * TreeMin(Node * x);
public:
  binTree();
  ~binTree();
  virtual void TreeInsert(int k);
  Node * TreeSearch(Node * X, int k);
  void ShowTree();
  int Root();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задача тянет на олимпиадную, пишу идею.

Решение будет сделано с помощью динамики по дереву.

Для каждого узла в дереве заведём список значений. Инициализация - в листах {0, Value}.
Пересчёт снизу вверху. Значение для узла пересчитывается примерно так (текущая вершина U):

```
for (auto left : U->left->list)
               U->list.add(left + U->Value);
for (auto right: U->left->right)
               U->list.add(right+ U->Value);
U->add(U->Value);
U->list->unique();
```

Я специально пишу псевдокодом, т.к. там может быть любая структура от специфики задачи (list vector set bitset) и т.д.

Для каждой вершины, где в списке есть `S`  будет последовательность ответ, которая заканчивается в ней. Её можно восстановить примерно так. Последовательность однозначно задаётся начальным и конченым элементом. Я верну только начальные.

```
list fun(Tree *U, int S){
   S -= U->Value;

   list tmp;
   if (S == 0)
      tmp.add(U);

   if (U->left->list.contains(S))
        tmp.add(fun(U->left,S);
   if (U->rigth->list.contains(S))
        tmp.add(fun(U->rigth,S);
   return tmp;
}
```

Сложно что-то порядка O(N^2 log N). Оптимизировать можно, но если выводить все последовательности то их может быть примерно столько же. Дальнейшие реализации/оптимизации вам виднее.

Comment: как то я не очень понял "схему" первого кода... Не могли бы вы, чуть более подробней описать.

Comment: а что именно не понятно?

Comment: Для каждого узла мы находим его сумму значений: Узел + Все что справа + Все что слева?

Comment: Если это так, то это неверное решение. С каждого узла можно опускаться либо влево, либо вправо. (Это условие задачи)

Comment: обновил. Кстати если совсем забить на скорость то можно просто перебрать верхнюю и нижнюю точку.

Comment: Я так и не понял как работает алгоритм.

`for (auto left : U->left->list)
               U->list.add(left + U->Value);
for (auto right: U->left->right)
               U->list.add(right+ U->Value);`

Вот каким образом здесь добавляются все значения справа от узла и слева?

п.с. Из-за занятости не мог этим заняться.

Comment: Видимо не весь код поправил с того раза, когда считал что нужно максимальное поддерево найти.

Comment: Вообще много уделил этой ереси (данному заданию) времени и практически нулевое продвижение. Даже "топорное" решение, которое раньше казалось вполне очевидным, не могу реализовать...

Comment: Собственно этот код рабочий, которые вы привели в комментарии. Идея такая - заводим список со всеми суммами, которые можно получить если верх - текущая вершина. Если мы знаем ответ для потомков, то ответ для вершины -  { {значение суммы в потомке + сама вершина} , сама вершина}. Именно это и написано в коде. Если что-то не выходит думаю есть смсысл попытаться собрать минимальный пример именно с этой задачей и выложить сюда.

Comment: ОК. С этим этапом вроде бы понял суть. Как реализую отпишу...

Answer (score 0):

Собственно вышло все гораздо проще. В структуре узла добавил:

```
list<pair<int, list<int>>> lSumNodes;
```

для подсчета всех возможных сумм.
 Так же добавил член класса:

```
list<list<int>> m_lSum;
```

куда сохранял все последовательности узлов, сумма которых равняется нужному числу.

Ну и все обработка происходит в трех методах класса:

```
void binTree::CulSum(int S)
{
  SumNode(m_pRoot);
  SearchSum(m_pRoot, S);
  ShowSum();
}
```

Подсчет всех возможных сумм для всех узлов:

```
void binTree::SumNode(Node * X)
{
if (X != NULL)
{
    SumNode(X->pLeft);
    SumNode(X->pRight);
    if (X->pLeft != NULL)
    {
        for (auto i : X->pLeft->lSumNodes)
        {
            i.second.push_front(X->Value);
            auto tmpPair = make_pair(i.first + X->Value, i.second);
            X->lSumNodes.push_back(tmpPair);
        }
    }
    if (X->pRight != NULL)
    {
        for (auto i : X->pRight->lSumNodes)
        {
            i.second.push_front(X->Value);
            auto tmpPair = make_pair(i.first + X->Value, i.second);
            X->lSumNodes.push_back(tmpPair);
        }
    }
    list<int> tmpList;
    tmpList.push_front(X->Value);
    auto tmp = make_pair(X->Value, tmpList);
    X->lSumNodes.push_back(tmp);
}
}
```

Поиск нужной суммы:

```
void binTree::SearchSum(Node * X, int S)
{
if (X != NULL)
{
    for (const auto i : X->lSumNodes)
        if (i.first == S)
            m_lSum.push_back(i.second);
    SearchSum(X->pLeft, S);
    SearchSum(X->pRight, S);
}
}
```

Метод решение хоть и топорный, но уже пофиг. Всем кто не прошел мимо - спасибо!